# Stack Snippets: Do we want them or need them, and are we allowed to have them?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm currently working on an answer that will include a bunch of code for a working example. I figured it'd be a great opportunity to try out the new snippets feature but it appears that we don't have it. [See here for info about Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

1. Considering the lack of coding in questions and answers, do we really need this feature?
2. Are there any reasons for why we *wouldn't* want this feature?
3. Are we allowed to have this feature?
4. When and how can we get it implemented if we do want it?

I personally think that over time, this feature would probably add a lot of value to our site. It would allow us to render SVGs on the page, show working examples of code and overall, we'd probably link to less external sources to support our answers (sending users away from our site less).

I can't think of a good reason why we wouldn't want it, except that maybe it'd be a pain to implement - but I doubt that very much.

**What does our wonderful community think?**

Answer (score 3):

> Considering the lack of coding in questions and answers, do we really
>   need this feature?
>   Are there any reasons for why we wouldn't want this feature?

I wouldn't see having this as a major benefit on our site. I still think that code-based web design questions are better off at Stack Overflow. Adding Snippets to our site would contradict that message. There's also something to be said about minimizing the amount of bloat in the post editor.

> Are we allowed to have this feature?
>
> When and how can we get it implemented if we do want it?

A list of posts that would benefit from this could be created to show that our site would be better off with it enabled. If a strong case is made, I don't see any reason why the SE team would disallow it.

Answer (score 1):

The big difference is most of the "code" here is CSS or javascript for applications.

Snippets isn't that beneficial for CSS -- a link to jsFiddle or CodePen works just as well. And I don't think "snippets" would really be beneficial at all for application-based javascript. Snippets are designed for web/browser based javascript and would most likely choke, fail, or die with application based javascript.

So, while not entirely useless, in my opinion, snippets would encourage more questions here which *really* belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: What benefit is there to having snippets for svg? Regarding image creation, screenshots work. if it's a code issue with svg, well... stackoverflow is better. I'm generalizing. But it's not like we get overwhelmed with SVG code questions.